# Angular library include stubs and testing helper files

Tags: angular, stub, angular-library

I have a simple Angular library for internal use with some pipes and directives, the library is used in several projects.
When the developers need to write the unit testing, they are creating a stub file for the pipe. They have the same stub in 5 projects duplicate always the same code.

What I want to do is provide this stub file for the pipe or directive, something similar to what does the `RouterTestingModule`, including a test module or include the stub itself inside my library, but I don't have any clue of how to do it.

Should I have to create a `LibraryTestingModule` and include it inside the main `public_api` and also include it in `LibraryModule`, that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround to solve this was the following:

At the same level of `src` path, create a `testing` folder. Inside it include the next files

```markdown
/src
/testing
┣ /src
┃ ┣ /stubs // my testing files here
┃ ┗ index.ts
┣ index.ts // barrel file
┣ package.json
┣ public_api.ts // similar to index.ts, entry point for public API of the package
┗ library-testing.module.ts // Angular module
```

For me, this was the trick, including the following lines inside the `package.json`

```json
{
  "ngPackage": {
    "lib": {
      "entryFile": "public_api.ts",
    }
  }
}
```

And with all these, now I can use `my-lib/some-pipe.ts` and in testing files, now I have access to `my-lib/testing/some-stub-pipe.ts`.